# Laravel 5 Eloquent relationships between 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models:

1. Father
2. Son
3. GrandSon

The relationship is obvious, a father can have many sons and his sons can have many grandsons.

***What I want to achieve is to find out how many grandsons a father has***.

I know that to find out how many sons he has I have to use this:

```
Father::find(1)->sons->count();
```

But how can I find out how many grandsons he has?

Comment: You'll need to loop through the sons, find out how many grandsons each has, and total them. Unfortunately I don't think Eloquent is going to be able to do this in a simpler way. In this particular case, I would wonder if it'd be worthwhile to write a manual SQL query that will return the number of grandsons for a father, then just call it like Father::find(1)->getGrandsonCount(); or something.

Comment: The relationship is obvious. The structure is however not. Is Father, the only table. Is there a table of sons as well. Then, do you have an `M..N` bridge or do you just self connect father to the father table. (making it in essence a people table)

Comment: Each model has one table, it's obvious. Father model $this->hasMany('App\Son'); Son model $this->hasMany('App\Grandson'); One to many relation between each.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loop through the Sons, you can define a `hasManyThrough` relation on the Father model, like so:

```
class Father
{
    public function grandsons()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('GrandSon', 'Son');
    }
}
```

Check here for reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jsphpl's answer, you can also continue chaining but with the methods instead of properties calls.

```
Father::find(1)->sons()->grandsons()->grandgrandsons()->count();
```

This is because `sons()` returns a relation and not a collection, so `grandsons()` will continue building the query from that `sons()` query. The same applies on `grandgrandsons()`.